# AWS Cost and Usage Report - Files not created in S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I created the S3 bucket first. With the necessary permission. And enabled notification to lambda function on all object:put.

I then created a Cost and Usage report and selected the above S3 bucket as the storage. Permissions look correct, as it could create/update the test file with the name "aws-programmatic-access-test-object"

Its been few days now, and CUR say it has been generating reports. But I cannot see the files in the S3 bucket.

Interestingly my lambda function is being invoked with notifications about object:put.

But the files are nowhere to be found.

Can someone help understand what might be happening please ?

[image: CUR config]

[image: S3 bucket]

[image: Lambda notification log]

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the directory with no name, above the aws-programmatic-access-test-object?